# Customizing the Recycle Bin in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I'd like to remove the words "recycle bin" from the screen but leave the icon there. I was able to do this in Windows XP, but I can't remember how to do it.

Also, I'd like to change the icon from a bin to something far more imaginative- I used to have the XP Plus Pack with the full and crescent moons as icons, but I don't particularly want these -- just something better than the choice of Microsoft icons that are offered.

Does anyone know how to solve these two bin issues and where might I look for new icons?

Answer (score 2):

Just right click the bin for the popup menu and use rename it. I could not delete the whole , but I could replace it by a single blank.

To change the icon right click the desktop. Select Personalize, Change Desktop icons, select the icon you want to replace and press change icon and select the icon you want.

Comment: Nice tip about the single blank.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-desktop-icon-text-on-windows-vista/